# How to run a server from a Tk Interface

Tags: server, tcl, tk-toolkit

So I have the following Tk interface and I want to run my clients and servers from it. 
The problem is that when I want to run the servers for example, it won't keep them opened and will execute them only once and then close them, like a normal Tcl script.
Can you tell me a way to open and run a script and keep it running without?

```
package require Tk

wm title . "Image Organizor"
grid [ttk::frame .c -padding "3 3 12 12"] -column 0 -row 0 -sticky nwes

grid [ttk::label .c.serverLabel -text "Servers"] -column 1 -row 1 -sticky e
grid [ttk::label .c.idServerLabel -text "Test Clients"] -column 2 -row 1 - sticky e
grid [ttk::button .c.slbl -text "Server" -command server] -column 1 -row 2 -sticky e
grid [ttk::button .c.idlbl -text "Id Server" -command idServer] -column 1 -row 3 -sticky e
grid [ttk::button .c.c1lbl -text "Client 1" -command client1] -column 2 -row 2 -sticky e
grid [ttk::button .c.c2lbl -text "Client 2" -command client2] -column 2 -row 3 -sticky e
grid [ttk::button .c.c3lbl -text "Client 3" -command client3] -column 3 -row 2 -sticky e
grid [ttk::button .c.c4lbl -text "Client 4" -command client4] -column 3 -row 3 -sticky e
grid [ttk::button .c.configlbl -text "Config" -command config] -column 1 -row 4 -sticky e

foreach w [winfo children .c] {grid configure $w -padx 5 -pady 5}

proc server {} {  
source ImageOrganizor/imageOrganizorServer.tcl
}

proc config {} {  
exec notepad.exe ImageOrganizor/config.txt
}
```

Comment: It depends on how the server script works. You might want to provide a little more detail. (Also, you're doing `source` inside a procedure; that can have unexpected consequences for the inexperienced.)

Comment: So I might have asked the wrong question. It doesn't have to be a server. I just want to know how to run a script from another. Let's say I have script A and script B and in script B I want to write a command that will start the execution of script A. I am also using TSC.

Answer (score 0):

- You could run the script in a separate thread using [thread::create](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/ThreadCmd/thread.htm)
- Or simply execute the script via shell in a separate process, e.g. `exec ImageOrganizor/imageOrganizorServer.tcl`
- Or `source` your code at root level and execute a proc to start your server, which might in turn either start a thread, execute or fork a new process.